# External UserManager and in-memory SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identity

I have a rather specific use case and I only find tutorials or articles on the internet doing both, UserManager and SignInManager, the one way (external) or the other (in-memory), but I just couldn't find a way to have an UserManager that uses external user data from an existing database and a SignInManager that stores tokens in-memory.

To be more specific on my use-case:

1. I have an external SQL database which already has the users and password hashes stored. Adding, updating or deleting those users is not allowed through the WebAPI so it's totally fine, if the IUserStore throws UnsupportedExceptions or InvalidOperationExceptions or something.
2. Furthermore I use authentication through JWT Bearer Tokens (`.AddJwtBearer()`). Those tokens should not be stored in the database where the user data is stored rather than being saved in an in-memory storage. It's totally okay if the stored tokens are gone on restart of the WebAPI server.

So, is this approach possible and if yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work this out by creating a custom user store (which implements `IUserPasswordStore<User>` and `IUserAuthenticationTokenStore<User>`. It gets the user data from said external database and gets (as well as sets) token data through a `TokenDbContext` I created which stores the `IdentityUserToken<UserKeyType>`. In addition to this I also needed a PasswordHasher which hashes the passwords the same way as the external user data storage does.

In the `Startup.cs` I then configured the whole has follows:

```
services.AddDbContext<TokenDbContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "tokens"));

services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddUserStore<ExternalUserStore>().AddSignInManager()
    .AddTokenProvider(Program.ApplicationName, typeof(DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>));

services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<User>, PasswordHasher>();

byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TheKeyIGotFromSomewhereTotallySafe");

services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie("Identity.Application")
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        };
    });
```